# Failing to find a good solution for backing up my data because of external hard drives failures and filesystem differences

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, backup

So my initial idea was to keep all (!) my files in three external hard drives: One for essentials
(1TB), and the other two - the exact copies of all the files (3TB each). By all files I mean
including my first drawings with CorelDraw when I was maybe 5. So I have bought ADATA
HM900 3TB (formatted as FAT32) portable hard drive (the one that needs the external
power source), and copied all my data from different computers there (about 800GB), both
Windows and linux (I've been using Windows for over a decade and now I'm on linux). I
have done the same with another hdd - Maxtor M3 Portable 1TB (1TB will suffice for now),
formatted as NTFS. I did not care about filesystem differences (including ext4 on my linux
machine), and it all worked well for some half a year.
However, although having used those hdds properly (no physical shaking, no holding
upside down, safe removal, etc.):

[1] I started getting input/output errors on my 3TB drive when copying files, mostly, but not
only(!) files containting .git foder. After that, copying process was terminated, and I could not
reach the folder that contained the "bad files". Even after disk restore (the default Windows
one, right click on disk properties) I did not manage to recover all the files. Btw, that was
certainly not the reason of files over 4GB, since I have none of those.

[2] I started getting input/output errors on my 1TB Maxtor hdd (NTFS) with the same
problem, with different folders and files though (there were no .git folders in this case)

[3] On copying files from linux PC to Maxtor hdd today I got a crash (the pc just froze, I
restarted it), after which neither linux nor Windows PCs detect this hdd after plugging it in

[4] I have bought another hdd: ADATA HC500 1TB, and formatted it with ext4. However,
windows PCs could not recognize this hdd (it appared on Control Panel->Disk management
though).
So, after having lost some files and some temper, I am wondering how could this situation
could be improved. Basically, the problem statement is this:

How could I use at least two HDDs (and which filesystems should I format them to) for
identical copies of all my files with the ability to plug them in both linux and Windows PCs (I
still use Windows sometimes), and minimizing the risk of such occurences happening again.
I have a Google Drive folder with all the necessary screenshots:
[gDrive_link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qd2oqegYIGpulU1hces-tAyeGW6TDutX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is probably a NAS or network attached storage.

Linux can mount it, and file sharing is a standard windows functionality.

Then you can implement RAID 5 or 6 on 3/4 drives, and if a drive fails RAID will rebuild it for you.

You can purchase NAS of different sizes.

Comment: To clarify on "you can purchase NAS of different sizes." You buy the NAS housing, for example a Synology, which have various models with a different number of drive bays. You can then choose the size of the drive you want to use for the bays.

Comment: NAS is OK to store and share files but not a very good backup solution since it is exposed to the same risks (burglary, fire...) as the PC (still better than what the OP is doing,though)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses. I was looking at this issue in a very simplistic way - there are external hard drives, they should be sufficient to store the data, is it not why they are for? However, the compatibility between different OSes and having lost some of my data really does make me consider more sophisticated options like NAS. Thank you for explaining :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use your Google drive that you already have. You may need to purchase extra space but you do not have to worry about drives going bad, how to get access from different operating systems, or how to create a NAS & which RAID you want to set up.

Also, if you still want to keep your files on your own drives you can still do that as well.

Comment: This is a good choice, although I would look into a way of creating volume images, etc. and encrypting them.  No sense in letting google (or any other company) have access to your raw digital self.

Comment: @ DBADon Yes, that's a considerable option. However, as @ivanivan points out, all the data really does make my raw digital self, although I have nothing to hide, but it is still a fact that is not very pleasant for it to be accessed by Google. As with encryption, I have had trouble with it in the past, and I look at this option as bringing potential dangers of losing the data.